Google Sheets, Array Formula, Target matching any of the cells in another tab
Currently I'm usinng the following formula
=ArrayFormula({"Somethingsomething"; if(len(X2:X),if((I2:I=3315)+(I2:I=3316)+(I2:I=3336)+(I2:I=3338)+(I2:I=3357)+(I2:I=3360)+(I2:I=3488)+(I2:I=3489)+(I2:I=3374)+(I2:I=3432)+(I2:I=3451)+(I2:I=3454)+(I2:I=3460)+(I2:I=3461)+(I2:I=3462),1.5,1),)})

I'd like to replace it with something like this:
=ArrayFormula({"Somethingsomething";if(len(X2:X),if(or(I2:I='othersheet'!E44:59),1.5,1),)})

But this formula gives me an error that says "Array arguments to EQ are of different size."
Any ideas?

COUNTIF
Use COUNTIF to compare each value to an array of values that are hardcoded or using a range reference.
COUNTIF  IF  INDEX  LEN
Range Reference
=INDEX({"Something";
   IF(LEN(X2:X), 
     IF(COUNTIF(othersheet!E44:E59, I2:I), 1.5, 1),)})
Hardcoded
=INDEX({"Something";
   IF(LEN(X2:X), 
     IF(
       COUNTIF({3315, 3316, 3336, 3338, 3357, 3360, 3488,
         3489, 3374, 3432, 3451, 3454, 3460, 3461, 3462}, I2:I),
        1.5, 1),)})

You can not use Or with arrayformula, that is why you got this error.
Here is updated one. and it can work.
=ArrayFormula({"Somethingsomething"; if(len(X2:X), if(ISNUMBER(MATCH(I2:I, 'othersheet'!E44:E59, 0)), 1.5, 1),)})
